# How to continue executing functions when `require` evaluates false

Tags: ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts, hardhat

I've got a question regarding modifiers, requires and function flow.

Here's a simple example for my point.

```js
contract Numbers {
    uint256[] private _numbers;

    modifier bigNumber(uint256 someNumber) {
        require(someNumber > 10, "Numbers: Number must be greater than 10");
        _;
    }

    function _addNumber(uint256 someNumber) private bigNumber(someNumber) {
        _numbers.push(someNumber);
    }

    function addNumbers(uint256[] memory _newNumbers) external {
        for (uint256 i = 0; i < _newNumbers.length; i++) {
            _addNumber(_newNumbers[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Let's say I call this function with `addNumbers([11, 12, 13, 8, 20, 21, 5, 22, 23]);`

I'd get an error when it reaches 8.

Is there a way to continue running the function with the following values?

I thought of adding an `if` to "catch" the error before, but maybe there's a better way of doing so.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The failed `require()` condition throws an exception.

---

In your case, the easiest way is to duplicate the condition in your `addNumbers()` function.

```
function addNumbers(uint256[] memory _newNumbers) external {
    for (uint256 i = 0; i < _newNumbers.length; i++) {

        // duplicated condition from the modifier
        if (_newNumbers[i] <= 10) {
            _addNumber(_newNumbers[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

---

If the `_addNumber()` function was `external` (i.e. executable from outside of the contract), you could use the try/catch expression.

```
// mind the changed visibility from `private` to `external`
function _addNumber(uint256 someNumber) external bigNumber(someNumber) {
    _numbers.push(someNumber);
}

function addNumbers(uint256[] memory _newNumbers) external {
    for (uint256 i = 0; i < _newNumbers.length; i++) {
        try this._addNumber(_newNumbers[i]) {
            // do nothing if didn't throw an exception
        } catch (bytes memory) {
            // do nothing if threw an exception
        }
    }
}
```

Try/catch is currently (v0.8) supported only for external calls and contract creation. That's why you'd need to make the `_addNumber()` function external to make it work.

Docs: https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.6/control-structures.html#try-catch